How to start caja using just left half screen with --geometry?
I use caja often with two windows open at the same time, each exactly half the screen.
By default, caja opens with a window a bit to the right, not exactly half the screen. The next caja opens a window on top. However, if the first caja window is reduced to half the screen to the left, the next opens in the right half.
Thus, how do I have the default location for the first caja open to the left half of the screen? I experimented with caja --geometry=960x1080 . (half my screen in pixels), but it was not doing what I wanted.
Two questions:

What is the correct geometry value for a screen 1920 by 1080?
How do you have caja open in the top left corner?


Your geometry values should be correct assuming you have no panels on the screen. As for positioning, though, caja has no option for positioning its window.
To accomplish the positioning, you'll need to launch caja from a script that calls wmctrl or xdotool. That assumes you're running X11 and not Wayland.
I don't have any experience with it, but a post entitled 'Re: Wayland replacements for xdotool, wmctrl, devilspie2' suggests that kdotool might be used to position the caja window in Wayland.

I think you are talking about two separate caja windows, but caja has a view option of "extra pane" that splits it in half and opens another window.   Perhaps that option will provide what you are looking for.

@tckosvic Unfortunately, it seems that the "extra pane" option is neither persistent across application sessions nor is there a command line option for it.

that may do for now. it is on F3 thus easy to use. Thank you for pointing it out!
